# How to quantify the difference ofspikes amplitude between 2 timeseries

Tags: r, time-series

I have a timeseries of model data and a timeseries of observation data, for the same timeframe.

The model fits the observations quite well, except when spikes occur: spikes are almost always overestimated, sometimes a little bit, sometimes a lot.

I would like to quantify this spikes' overestimation, but I don't want this measure to be "polluted" by the baseline bias evolution.

See the dummy example below:

[image]

```
data <- data.table(t     = 1:40,
                   obs   = c(0,0.5,0,3,0,0.5,0,0.5,0,0.5,0,6,0,0.5,0,0.5,0,3,0,0.5,0,0.5,0,3,0,0.5,0,0.5,0,0.5,0,6,5,6,0,0.5,0,3,0,0.5),
                   model = c(0.4,1.1,0.5,4,0.3,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.4,0.9,-0.1,7,0.4,0.9,0.5,0.9,0.3,6,-0.5,0,-0.6,0.1,-0.3,4,-0.1,0.9,-0.1,0.9,0.1,0.5,-0.1,7,6,8,0,1.1,0.1,6,0,1.1))
data <- melt(data, id.vars = "t")

ggplot(data, aes(x = t, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

I don't care about the model errors of values between 0 and 1. Note that in real case the baseline error is not always between 0 and 1, mean biais may increase over time, etc.

I need to concentrate only on the peaks, and to find a way to say "model A modelize peaks better than model B", or "the model modelize peaks quite well within timeframe A but the peak modelization error is x times more important  within timeframe B".

Comment: Calculating a variance of the delta between model and real data is one straightforward way. Variance is quadratic measure which will grow fast in case the "peaks" are underfitted.